# Shortcodes в wordpress gallery

Tags: wordpress

Нужно сделать элемент с shortcodes. На определённой странице у нас размещены картинки в shortcodes, сам шорткод имеет вид:

```
[gallery size="medium" ids="1, 2, 3"]
```

Но проблема в том, что на странице эти картинки не имеют атрибута

```
rel="nofollow"
```

Как мне можно перехватить ту ссылку которую он создает и записать в нее новый атрибут? Я так понимаю нужно с помощью функции `do_shortcodes` но как именно, это реализовать я не понимаю, какие параметры она будет принимать, и как будет возвращать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [мануале](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) вп есть пример:

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery option1="value1"]'); ?>
```

Т.е. результат функции `do_shortcode`, которая принимает, как параметр сам шорткод, можно присвоить переменной. Результат будет в виде строки, соответственно, можно пройтись по этой строке, например, функцией [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) и заменить подстроки, вида `<img` на `<img rel='nofollow'`

Comment: Да, я видел этот пример, а вы знаете как сделать так, что бы он принимал нужные мне id картинок? Просто в примере я так понимаю, могу прописать свои id и уже дальше заменить...

Comment: А пробовали ваш шорткод передать? Который [gallery size="medium" ids="1, 2, 3"]

Comment: Я так понимаю мне нужно реализовать функцию. Которая в параметры примет мой шорткод, а уже в теле функции добавить нужный мне атрибут. Но я не знаю как получить мою ссылку на определенную галерею, то есть на сформированную ссылку с одной картинкой. Есть мысль, что это как то хуком можно сделать, но опять же я в рамках wordpress не знаю как это сделать. Передать шорткод имеется ввиду в его тело с админки вложить нужный мне атрибут?

Comment: Плохо понял последний коммент. Вы не знаете, как получить шорткод вашей галереи? [Вот тут](https://mblogm.ru/wordpress-guide/wordpress-functions/shortcode-gallery/) можно увидеть

Comment: Спасибо, буду дальше уже сам реализовывать пробовать с вашими советами!